# Exception report component for VisualStudio C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, delphi, exception

I'm using [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) component in Delphi to **catch unmanaged exception** and create a full report with email capability.
What component (paid or free) with same features exist for **C++** and **C#** compatible with **Visual Studio**.

Mandatory features:

- Full report creation
- email capability
- Minor customization
- None to minor source code modification

Comment: It's not quite the same in C++, but you can do something similar with SEH or a debugger process. I believe a friend of mine did it, in project Aedra, but can't give details on how. No idea about C#, so not posting as an answer.

Comment: Why is there a close vote ? Mr 'close', please explain with a small comment. please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_dotnet.php) .Net edition, which is equivalent to MadExcept for Delphi and has .Net version for Visual studio.

Comment: that's a nice idea if you're already a EurekaLog user on Delphi.

Comment: Accepted answer as it has the Delphi compatibility.

Comment: I believe the .net edition of eurekalog was discontinued some time ago, adding a note here for anyone who might go looking in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can use (commercial) [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) - it has several features (obfuscation, dependency merging...) and comes with a similar capability regarding error/exception reporting with eMail/SOAP etc.

You can use any feature without activating the other features (no source code modification necessary although it comes with an SDK for customization if need be)... BUT it works only with .NET - so if you are not using C++/CLI then this tool only covers the C# part of your question...

(not affiliated just a happy customer)

Answer (score 5):

For Visual C++ try open source [CrashRPT](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) for Windows, if your app is written in Visual C++.  Doesn't work with C#.